# How to fix custom scheme opening in maccatalyst when app is closed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, deep-linking, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

## Problem & context

I am building a Maccatalyst app that uses a custom scheme (deep-link).

When my app is running and I click on the link to my app, my app opens and receives the opening url.

However, when my app is closed, and I click on the link to my app, it opens but does not receive the opening url.
This issue does not occur on ios.

(FYI, the app is written with react-native 0.59, but the issue is not on the javascript side).

Can anyone help me on this ?

## Code

Her is my AppDelegate.m file

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CGGeometry.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                             moduleName:@"myapp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  // Listen to incoming app links during app execution
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
  // Listen to universal links in iOS and tvOS
  // does not work when app is closed in debug mode
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                   continueUserActivity:userActivity
                     restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ...
}

@end
```

## What I have tried

- I checked that the issue is not on the javascript side because when the app is closed, neither application:openURL:options nor application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler (from the app delegate) are called.
- As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app?language=objc), I tried to see if anything was sent in launchOptions in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. But that is apparently only called on the very first launch.
- I have read the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app?language=objc) but couldn't find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was in the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application?language=objc)

`This method is not called if your implementations return NO from both the application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods. (If only one of the two methods is implemented, its return value determines whether this method is called.) If your app implements the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method instead of application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, this method is called to open the specified URL after the app has been initialized.`

So I need to watch for the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` in the options of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Next time, I'll read the docs more carefully.